# Ministry of Accuraccy and Morale - Retrieving Dimethyl Sulfoxide

Tags: the-outer-worlds

Hi currently I'm stuck in the quest mentioned above, when hacking the computer I've found the hint that Caroline has an ongoing feud with her coworker. The lab door is blockaded and unfortunately she is nowhere to be seen. I have forcefully entered the place and thus I guess she won't naturally turn up anymore.

Is there a second way into the lab? How do i proceed to finish the quest?

Comment: She's not upstairs in the cafeteria?

Comment: Nope, no named NPCs in the cafeteria to be seen, searched the sewers and around the house and did not find any way to unlock the door :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can just procceed by calling in an elevator in the backroom i seemed to have missed. Going peaceful or not does not seem to influence that part, even though your quest tracker still wants you to meet the scientist.